# Laravel 5.2 InvalidArgumentException in FilesystemManager.php line 121: Driver [] is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

**Filesystem.php**

I have some problem when I try to create a new disk in Laravel 5.2

```
'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'manifest' => [ // it´s works if only stay this 
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('../../manifestations_media'), 
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'documentos' => [ // if add this nothing works
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('../../documentos'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
        ],
        

    ],
```

I don't know why it fails, but if I try adding a new disk fails all configuration doesn't work. Can somebody help me understanding why, please?

```
$mytime = time();
        $ext = pathinfo($request->myfile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = sha1_file($request->file('myfile')->getRealPath()) . $mytime . "." . $ext;
        Storage::disk('documentos')->put($filename, file_get_contents($request->file('myfile')->getRealPath()));
        DB::update('update cities set document = ? where id = ?', [$filename, $data]);
```

Comment: From the question, I don't get the exact problem. If it is not working, what error you're getting?

Comment: The error it´s de label of topic, if add documentos in Laravel 5.2, i can´t upload file manifest either documentos, but if i remove docuementos manifest works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem change the version Laravel 6. This mistake doesn´t. I dont known why happen In Laravel 5.2. It´s possible that i have changed something that i can´t remember, but for the moment it´s works